# Is there a way to handle extra slashes at beginning of url using jersey and guice?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, guice, guice-servlet

I have a REST api put together using jersey and guice for dependency injection.  Everything works great, I have FEATURE_CANONICALIZE_URI_PATH and FEATURE_NORMALIZE_URI turned on and that handles extra slashes in almost all cases.  For instance:

```
http://localhost:8080/my_service/param1//param2
```

The problem is I can't sort out the proper way to handle an extra slash at the beginning of the url (before the service path).  Like this:

```
http://localhost:8080//my_service/param1/param2
```

This is how I have stuff set up currently:

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>MyServletConfig</listener-class>
</listener>
```

MyServletConfig.java

```
public class MyServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                bind(MyService.class);

                guiceContainerConfig.put(ResourceConfig.FEATURE_NORMALIZE_URI, "true");
                guiceContainerConfig.put(ResourceConfig.FEATURE_CANONICALIZE_URI_PATH, "true");

                serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, guiceContainerConfig);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param1}/{param2}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String get(
            @PathParam("param1") final String param1,
            @PathParam("param2") final String param2) {

        return "{\"param1\":\"" + param1 + "\"}";
    }
}
```

I can see that the issue really is that the request with the // before the service name is not actually getting handled by the servlet because it is not matched in the url-mapping of the filter-mapping but I'm just not really sure the right solution.  Do I need to do an url rewrite before that url is matched to a servlet or is there a better way to map the request urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick leads:

http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ is a java web filter. It is a very powerful tool just like Apache's mod_rewrite.
Setup the filter with classic htaccess rewrites from http://www.mydigitallife.info/redirect-or-rewrite-to-remove-double-or-multiple-slashes-in-url/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jetty, just add the module [`rewrite-compactpath`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/startup-modules.html).

> ```
>  Module: rewrite-compactpath
>        : Add a rule to the rewrite module to compact paths so that double slashes
>        : in the path are treated as a single slash.
>  Depend: rewrite
>     XML: etc/rewrite-compactpath.xml
> ```